# How to avoid Java request.getQueryString() get escaped string

Tags: servlets, query-string, urlencode

I have a Servlet that process a `QueryString` from a JSP form.

When the JSP send the information to the Servlet, it puts on the URL the query, like this:

```
https://www.mywebsite.com/search?query=Barcelona
```

And i receive the data inside the Servlet in this way:

```
String query = request.getQueryString();
// query will receive "Barcelona"
```

Everything works alright. The problem comes when the string contains characters from other encodings like russian, chinese, arabic, etc. So, if I put the URL like:

```
https://www.mywebsite.com/search?query=Медеуский
```

I will receive in the query variable the following text:

```
String query = request.getQueryString();
// query will receive " %D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9"
```

So, how could I avoid the escaped conversion?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `URLDecoder.decode(request.getQueryString(), "UTF-8")`

or

- String unicodeQuery = new String(query.getBytes(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
- String unicodeQuery = new String(query.getBytes("ISO_8859_1"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
- String unicodeQuery = new String(query.getBytes(Charset.defaultCharset()), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

Comment: Thank you! That's it!
The first solution worked perfectly!